# Linking SFML to my programm in fedora (c++) - makefile?

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, fedora, sfml

Can anyone tell me how to link to external libraries using a makefile or other? I looked on the interwebs and couldn't really find anything. a detailed tutorial would be su[per helpful!

Comment: Add `-l<library-name>` to the compiler/linker flags. For SFML, it'd be `-lsfml-network -lsfml-audio ...`.

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-linux.php).